# Can I change background color of a Row in Datatable base on value of a Column ( Lightning Component )?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable

```
<aura:attribute name="RowsCount" type="Integer" default="0"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordList" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="allData" type="List" />
<aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="sortedBy" type="String" default="Name"/>
<aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="string" default="asc" />
<aura:attribute name="searchResult" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="searchKeyword" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="Date1" type="date"/>
<aura:attribute name="Date2" type="date"/>
<aura:attribute name="Message" type="boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="TotalNumberOfRecord" type="integer" default="0" />
<aura:attribute name="selectedStudents" type="List"/>
<aura:attribute name="selectedRowsCount" type="Integer" default="0"/>

<lightning:layout multipleRows="true" horizontalAlign="center">
        <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-small" size="12">
            <lightning:datatable keyField="Id" data="{!v.recordList}"
                                 columns="{!v.columns}"
                                 hideCheckboxColumn="false"
                                 onsort="{!c.updateSorting}"
                                 sortedBy="{!v.sortedBy}"
                                 sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"
                                 onrowaction="{! c.handleRowAction }"
                                 onrowselection="{! c.updateSelectedText}"
                                 class="table-test"
                                 />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
```

this is the code for datatable

```
getStudents : function(component, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getStudentList");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        var data;
        if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
            component.set('v.columns', [
                { label: 'Họ', fieldName: 'HoHocSinh__c', type: 'text', cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: 'Tên', fieldName: 'StudentUrl', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label:{fieldName:"TenHocSinh__c"}, target:'_self'}, cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: 'Ngày sinh', fieldName: 'NgaySinh__c', type: 'date', cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: 'Giới tính', fieldName: 'GioiTinh__c', type: 'checkbox', cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: 'Điểm 1', fieldName: 'Diem1__c', type: 'number', cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: 'Điểm 2', fieldName: 'Diem2__c', type: 'number', cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: 'Điểm 3', fieldName: 'Diem3__c', type: 'number', cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: 'Điểm TB', fieldName: 'DiemTB__c', type: 'number', cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: 'Tình trạng', fieldName: 'TinhTrang__c', type: 'text', cellAttributes:{class:{fieldName:'ShowClass'}} },
                { label: '',  type: 'button', initialWidth: 150 , typeAttributes: {label:'Cập nhật', disable:'false', name:'editRecord', value:"edit" } },
                { label: '',  type: 'button', initialWidth: 150 , typeAttributes: {label:'Xóa', disable:'false',name:'deleteRecord', value:"delete" } }
            ]);
```

this is helper file to fetch data.

i got a suggest that should apply css to column level but i don't know to do it.

Comment: It will be easier for us to help you if you copy-paste your code as *code*, not as *screenshots*. Please [edit] your question to include the actual code as code. You can use the `{}` code format button to make sure it appears correctly when saving.

Comment: i edited it , thank you for your advice